# Git status - Not showing states of remote Repo

Tags: git

Just starting with Git and I'm finding something strange.

I have a git repo on github - https://github.com/ankh2054/modx.git
I have a directory on my sever /home/Modx

I've added the github as a remote Repo, and if I run the command

```
git remote -v
```

I get the following output

```
origin  https://github.com/ankh2054/modx.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ankh2054/modx.git (push)
```

But when I run git status, it does not mention anything about my remote Repo. So when I update and commit files locally it does't prompt me about my local being more up to date than my remote Repo.

```
git status

On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What I should say I believe is:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: Did you do a `git fetch`?

Comment: I created the repo on Github and then ran: git remote add origin https://github.com/ankh2054/modx.git

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the output of `git branch -avvv`.

If you don't see any remote branch, that means you need to:

```
 git fetch
 git branch -u origin/master
```

From there you will have a comparison between `master` and `origin/master`.
And you will be able to do a simple `git push`.